# How to Add Open file selection dialog box using c++?

Tags: c++, matlab

Im a newbie and want to know if this is possible so that it may help in my project which is only in c++. This is something similar to "uigetfile" in matlab.I use Ubuntu.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add windowing capability to your program.  The **standard** C++ language has no facilities for dialog boxes.

Windowing is platform specific.  You may find windowing frameworks that are cross-platform.

Dialog box creation is either OS dependent or windowing framework dependent.

You didn't specify in your post the OS you are using.

Comment: Sorry , I dont know it was OS dependent .Im linux (ubuntu) user .Can you please guide me more

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ GUI framework cross platform".  Read up on reviews and pick one.

Answer (score 0):

Graphical User Interfaces (GUI or UI) are very complex systems that depends on many layers of hardware and software:

- The hardware, especially the graphic card help for drawing and showing the result on screen.
- Driver: To access the Graphic card. This is already platform-dependent.
- Operating system: Give you facilities to user the graphic card and usually a library for drawing your GUI.

This mean, there is not a standard way to make a GUI, and that C++ stay outside of the mess.

However, some libraries abstract the different systems and provide single API for creating GUI, this obviously relay on the library having implemented the specific platform details, so it will never be 100% cross-platform.

Examples of GUI libraries are:

- QT (e.g. used for KDE)
- GDK (e.g. used for GNOME / UNITY)
- wxWidgets
- ...